# Determining target TD when TR is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given some click event for a table row:

```
$("tr.somerow").click(function(){
    //do some stuff
    //can I determine the TD under the cursor at the time of clicking?
})
```

Can I determine which TD (or any child elements) was under the cursor at the time of clicking?

Comment: It would be easier to put the click event on the TDs and determine the TR from there instead.

Comment: @RoToRa - I did think of that, but I wasn't sure about binding potentially hundreds of cells compared with dozens of rows. You've also got to contend with padding and whether or not the gaps between the cells will yield a click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("tr.somerow").click(function(e){
  var target = $(e.target); // sets to the td or the element that was clicked
  //do some stuff
})
```

To find the clicked `<td>` regardless of any child elements, use `var target = $(e.target).closest("td");` instead.

Comment: You example has a small bug. If I have `<td><a>Anchor</a></td>` and click the anchor text, it will not select the `td`. You need a `closest` selector, as well.

Comment: @shesek, the question says "Can I determine which TD (`or any child elements`)"

Answer (score 5):

If you are able to change the script then do so to take advantage of jquerys [.delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) function. This avoids having multiple bound click events and also in the event handler the this context will be that of the clicked td element.

```
$('tr.somerow').delegate('td', 'click', function(){

   //this refers to the td

})
```

Comment: This is the nicest solution, with the only caveat that the developer will need to know delegate will bind to any future 'tr.somerow' that gets created.

Comment: @David it won't. You're confusing it with live.

Comment: @shesek
".delegate( selector,eventType,handler ) Returns: jQuery
Description: Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements."

"Now or in the future" - delegate is the same as live, but it also handles rebinding `this`, and it gets called a bit earlier in event propagation.

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: @David Souther - you are incorrect - it would match any new td's inside of the selector but not new tr.somerow elements

Answer (score 2):

A couple mostly correct answers, but one misses the closest, and the other does a lot of unnecessary error handling.

```
$("tr.selector").click(function(e){
    var td = $(e.target).closest('td');
});
```